# jQuery horizontal layout resets to scrollLeft 0 on Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I have created a custom wordpress template (horizontal layout) which makes extensive use of jQuery.
All the Javascript/CSS is written from scratch and makes no use of any ready-made library.
Things are working fine on IE8, Chrome. But Firefox is giving me some trouble.

Go to http://madhur.me, click projects, it should scroll horizontally to the projects section, and click on "Project#1" or "Project#2"

On clicking the name of any project, it should scroll down smoothly.
But what happens on firefox is, since the height changes, and since its a horizontal layout, the page resets to scrollLeft(0) or to the extreme left.
As far as i think, its not a Javascript issue, but a browser issue.
Maybe something wrong with my CSS, which makes the browser to do so.

Comment: #Madhur - Not sure, what do you mean. Please give a screenshot with some details on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On clicking the name of any project,
>   it should scroll down smoothly.

Its working fine FF 3.6.13.

Comment: I have applied an ugly workaround for now so the issue is not so visible, but its still unsolved. Click Projects, Click on a project with a content long enough to show up the vertical scrollbars. Now close the project. Ideally it should be showing the projects section, but it scrolls back to left and shows the About section. Works fine on IE 8/Chrome, but the issue is with Firefox.

Comment: well i tried its working fine in my Firefox. My FF Details                  

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)

Comment: Try updating your Firefox once and check.